# Read data from XML using node values in C#

Tags: c#, xml

I know this question is asked so many times. But I couldn't find a proper answer yet.

I have an XML file with some country codes and country names in it. Here it is.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <CountryCodeNames>
      <Country CountryID="0" EnglishCountryName="NOT DEFINED" ArabicCountryName="NOT DEFINED"/>
      <Country CountryID="001" EnglishCountryName="ALGERIA    " ArabicCountryName="الجزائر"/>
      <Country CountryID="002" EnglishCountryName="ANGOLA    " ArabicCountryName="       انجولا "/>
      <Country CountryID="003" EnglishCountryName="BOTSWANA     " ArabicCountryName="       بوتسوانا "/>
      <Country CountryID="004" EnglishCountryName="BURUNDI     " ArabicCountryName="    بوروندى "/>
      <Country CountryID="005" EnglishCountryName="CAMERON REPUBLIC     " ArabicCountryName="     جمهوريه الكمرون  "/>
      <Country CountryID="006" EnglishCountryName="CENTRAL AFRICAN REP.   " ArabicCountryName="جمهوريهافريقياالوسطي "/>
      <Country CountryID="007" EnglishCountryName="CHAD   " ArabicCountryName="     تشاد  "/>
      <Country CountryID="008" EnglishCountryName="CONGO (BRAZZAVILLE)    " ArabicCountryName="  )الكونغوا(برازافيل       "/>
      <Country CountryID="009" EnglishCountryName="CONGO (DRC)" ArabicCountryName="جمهورية الكنغوليس"/>
      <Country CountryID="010" EnglishCountryName="BENIN (PEOPLE REPUB)       " ArabicCountryName="جمهوريه بنين الشعبيه"/>
      <Country CountryID="011" EnglishCountryName="ETHIOPIA     " ArabicCountryName="     أثيوبيا "/>
      <Country CountryID="012" EnglishCountryName="GABON    " ArabicCountryName="     جمهوريه الجابون  "/>
      <Country CountryID="013" EnglishCountryName="GHANA   " ArabicCountryName="        غانا "/>
      <Country CountryID="014" EnglishCountryName="GUINEA       " ArabicCountryName="    غينيا "/>
</CountryCodeNames>
```

Now in my windows form I got the CountryID and I want to read EnglishCountryName from this XML file according to the CountryID I have. This is so far I have tried. Dont know much about XML file reading. Please help.

```
string natxmlcode = crdv4.smartcardData.NationalityCode.ToString();
                XmlDocument xd = new XmlDocument();
                string xmlpath = @"D:\CountriesNameList.xml";
                xd.Load(xmlpath);
                string nationality = xd.SelectSingleNode("CountryCodeNames/CountryID="+natxmlcode+"/EnglishCountryName").InnerText;
```

'natxmlcode' is CountryID.

Comment: I haven't used XML in a few years, so my memory may be a little rusty.. but I believe your XPATH should look a little more like:  `$"//CountryCodeNames/Country[CountryID=\"{natcode}\"]"`.  Then you will need to read the returned XmlNode's EnglishCountryName attribute to get the value you are after.

Comment: you mean i should change my 'xmlpath' to this. But will this access the xml file which is stored in my D drive?

Comment: No.  Not `xmlpath`.  [XPATH](https://www.google.com?q=XPATH).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to use XDocument; it is easier and cleaner to use than XmlDocument.

To select the name, use this code:

```
string natcode = crdv4.smartcardData.NationalityCode.ToString();
string xmlpath = @"D:\CountriesNameList.xml";
XDocument xd = XDocument.Load(xmlpath);

string nationality = xd.Descendants("Country")
       .FirstOrDefault(c => c.Attribute("CountryID").Value.Equals(natcode))
       .Attribute("EnglishCountryName").Value;
```

Note: you will need the `System.Xml.Linq` namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Sebastian's answer really helped in VS 2013. But I wanted the same functionality in VS 2008 with .Net framework 2.0. So this is what I did and working fine. Thanks to Sam Axe.

```
string xmlpath = @"D:\CountriesNameList.xml";
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.Load(xmlpath);
XmlNode node = xml.SelectSingleNode("//CountryCodeNames/Country[@CountryID="+natxmlcode+"]");
string nationality = node.Attributes[1].Value.ToString();
```